# Get same value when downloading String from Text file

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

So I have a text file on a server that contains a phone number of a person who had just called in. I am using a timer event in my program in order to see if the file has any text and then proceed to print the string of the phone number. I keep getting a different string. The phone number would be 8012939202 or something like that yet it always prints 4356591376 no matter what value the text file is. What could be the issue? My code is below (I censored the url).

```
    func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
    // Scheduling timer to Call the function **Countdown** with the interval of 1 seconds
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateCounting), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
func updateCounting()
{
    let urls = URL(string : "http://www.xxxxxx.net/CallerID/" + accountID + "/phone.txt")
    do{
        let phonenumber = try String(contentsOf: urls!, encoding: .ascii)
        print(phonenumber)
    }catch{

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the encoding to utf8 instead of ascii?

Comment: Yeah. I have tried that. It is an ascii file. The weird thing is I turned off the internet and it still pushed the same results. I have the url correct